# Is this soil ok?

Tags: soil, potting-soil

I just want to buy a new potting soil and I found this in my local market. I wonder if this is ok for plants like cactus lemons etc. Don't know much about soil.

[image]

Comment: It is made in Germany, here in the Netherlands that usually means it is of good quality ;-) It is hard to tell if this is good soil seeing only the packaging. But for most plants just normal potting soil is good, for cacti maybe add some perlite to the soil.

Comment: it says white peat 65%, black peat 35% is this good ?

Comment: substrate  in English usually refers to a layer of something in the ground,often rock or  crushed gravel. If that bag says 65%white peat and 35% black peat,that would suggest its just peat, not actually potting soil.